# How to make PDF index/bookmarks/outline always folded/collapsed/wrapped on Okular

Tags: pdf, pdftk, okular

[image] This behavior is file specific and not due to evince or okular since there are pdf files that are always folded .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Use pdfedit . You can install it in Linux from [here](https://gist.github.com/bmaupin/a23161b50f27179e6e5b064d6066b034) (it worked in ubuntu 18.04 LTS bionic beaver).</s>

Type pdfedit in terminal to open the program and load your pdf file .

In the right side of the window you will see a tree . Open outlines . Then find each node of the pdf outline you want to be always display wrapped . Open that node and left click on it and choose add item to dictionary. This item should have property name Count be of int type and value equal to the negative of the already existing Count property (left click on the count property and choose show string representation , look at left down window and you will see the value that is has) . Replace the already existing Count property and that node will always be wrapped when you open the pdf .

I still do not know a faster way to do that in linux .

Edit : A somewhat faster solution is to use [jPdfTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) . Download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdftweak/files/jpdftweak/jpdftweak-1.1/jpdftweak-compact-1.1.zip/download?use_mirror=netcologne&download=) and read the README.txt file on how to run it via terminal .