# Can pdftk fold bookmarks?

Tags: pdftk

I want to fold pdf bookmarks.

[How to make PDF index/bookmarks/outline always folded/collapsed/wrapped on Okular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793627/how-to-make-pdf-index-bookmarks-outline-always-folded-collapsed-wrapped-on-okula)

I only see that pdftk can insert bookmarks, but not how to fold bookmarks.

https://opensource.com/article/22/1/pdf-metadata-pdftk

Is there a way to use pdftk to fold bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

Not with `pdftk`, but you can do it with the community version of `cpdf`:

```
cpdf -bookmarks-open-to-level <n> in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Where  is 0 to close all bookmarks, 1 to open just to the next level (maybe chapters) and 2 to the next level (maybe sections?)

```
cpdf -list-bookmarks in.pdf
```

will show you the current levels.